# Android Crop Image crash

Tags: android

I'm currently using the following code to ask the user to choose an image from memory and to crop it, but it keeps crashing.

```
      Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
         android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

  i.putExtra("crop", "true");
         i.putExtra("outputX", 90);
         i.putExtra("outputY", 90);
         i.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
         i.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
         i.putExtra("scale", true);

         startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

And then, inside "onActivityResult" I've found data.getData() is null (whether when I comment out the "crop" extra it contains the image Uri), and extras.getParcelable("data") is null as well. :S

Does anybody have any clue, please?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, fixed adding i.putExtra("return-data", true);  :D